# javascript image slideshow (jquery or YUI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, slideshow

I am looking for a javascript based image slideshow solution. Requirements I received:

- A few images are added to the slideshow, and it fades one image after another and then starts again from the first image
- There should be a navigation in order to manually go to the next / previous image
- There should be the option to pause the slideshow and continue again

Can the jquery cycle plugin handle these? Are there any alternatives for the YUI 2 framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery Cycle plugin can definiately handle this.  Check out [this page of examples](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah, there is a demo with prev / next links, havent seen this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For YUI 3:

http://freshcutsd.com/yui-slideshow/

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

The YUI Carousel component seems like a good fit:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_circular_source.html

Comment: Yes, I already tried it and it looks good BUT I cant find a way to change the animation from sliding to fading.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the great [Lightbox Clones Matrix](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/). It's mainly based around ones which open in a div above your content, but many offer slideshow capabilities. Just use the checkboxes in the top right to filter to what you want.