# Simple image slideshow (example included)

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I stumbled upon this website: http://www.liptongreenmint.ro/

I like their small and simple slideshow with 5 pictures that are moving independently. I tried to understand how it's done by looking at the code, but came short.

I hope someone can open my eyes here. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript image slideshow (jquery or YUI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244998/javascript-image-slideshow-jquery-or-yui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the link provided in the jCarousel.js file included in the `<head>` section of this website: [jCarousel - Riding carousels with jQuery](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they're using [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel) and [Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) which are JQuery Plugins